# res.write() not working inside socket.on method

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

```
router.get('/optimizationStatus', (req, res) => {
    console.log('test');

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    });
    let data = {
        .. some Data
    };
    socket.emit('optimization', data);
    socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('MESSAGE', data);
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
    });
    req.on('close', () => {
        socket.off('optimization');
    });
});
```

I have written this code that's on request hit it emits to optimization by sending some payload `data` but it is not working
.

```
`socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('MESSAGE', data);
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
    }); `
```

The console.log() it is working fine it is printing data when message is returning but  `res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);` is not working

When i am trying this in postman it just keep loading but the logs are coming in the server? What am i missing

Comment: Do you have to close the response when you want it to be finished?

Comment: That's not the problem @user253751

Comment: how do you know it isn't?

Comment: oh, I see it is an event stream, so it's probably not meant to be closed

Comment: what is this router thing, what library is it from?